# Allow only one True argument in Function

Tags: python, validation, arguments

Given the following function:

```
def controls_validation(creation_mode=False, existence_mode=False, integrity_mode=False):
    if creation_mode:
        # Do X
    elif existence_mode:
        # Do Y
    elif integrity_mode:
        # Do Z
    else:
        raise ValueError("At least one arg required.")
```

I want to validate the arguments so that only one True argument is allowed. Naturally, my else/elif statements have an specific order, I wouldn't want the user to for example set "creation_mode" and "integrity_mode" to True and as a consequence have the function happily do X just because "creation mode" is first, even though something was clearly wrong and chances are the function is no validating the mode the user intended to validate.

I have read that validating arguments is not a thing you should do in Python unless you have a very specific reason. Should I even bother doing this? Or is it the user responsibility to read the documentation and know how to use it?

Thanks in advance for your opinions.

Comment: The whole idea is somewhat strange.  If the arguments are mutually excluse, why not have three separate methods for the different kinds of validation?

Comment: If exactly one true value is required then why not pass in a parameter that can take one of three values instead of three booleans?

Comment: @samgak I thought about passing multiple strings ('creation_mode', 'existence_mode' or 'integrity_mode') to a single arg but I felt it was uglier to ask the user for a specific string than ask them for a boolean.

Comment: @BrenBarn Maybe I am too new,  but I guess I have this idea of trying to avoid classes unless they are really needed and not use them for simpler stuff like this.

Comment: Validating input's gotta be a thing.  I don't think the attitude "it's the user's responsibility" is ever healthy.  You can add like one line of code to make it easier for the users, and the evident model of the users you have in your head is that sometimes they'll benefit from it, i.e., they're likely to sometimes mis-enter their choices.  So validate the freaking arguments.  I'd probably do it at the moment they enter the second "true" value, honestly; ask 'em if they really want to do that.

Comment: @Paul User input validation is sound. That's not what is being discussed though. Arguments to functions are not always supplied by the user. Often supplied by programmer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan fair enough.  I read the question to suggest that these arguments were direct from user input...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this be closer to what you're looking for:

```
def controls_validation(creation_mode=False, existence_mode=False, integrity_mode=False):
    if creation_mode and not existence_mode and not integrity_mode:
        print("creation")
    elif existence_mode and not creation_mode and not integrity_mode:
        print("existence")
    elif integrity_mode and not creation_mode and not existence_mode:
        print("integrity")
    else:
        raise ValueError("At least one arg required.")
```

This would ensure only one arg is inputted to be true while the other ones are false.

I would consider using `try`, `except` so it doesn't terminate the program upon incorrect entry. That all depends if you're looking for direct input from user at time of execution.

If you want something a little more scalable then you can start with this and improve on it.

```
def controls_validation(mode):
    modes = ['creation_mode', 'existence_mode', 'integrity_mode']
    check = mode.split()
    count = 0
    for w in check:
        count += 1
    if count == 1:
        if mode == 'creation_mode':
            print('creation_mode')
        elif mode == 'existence_mode':
            print('existence_mode')
        elif mode == 'integrity_mode':
            print('integrity_mode')
        else:
            pass
    else:
        raise ValueError("At least one arg required.")
```

Compacted yet again:

```
def controls_validation(mode):
    m = ['creation_mode', 'existence_mode', 'integrity_mode']
    check = mode.split()
    if len([v for v in check if mode in m]) is 1:
        if mode == 'creation_mode':
            print('creation_mode')
        elif mode == 'existence_mode':
            print('existence_mode')
        elif mode == 'integrity_mode':
            print('integrity_mode')
        else:
            pass
    else:
        raise ValueError("At least one arg required.")
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't though about this, however this doesn't scale well at least in my situation,  in which I could have up to 10 arguments and this could get complicated to set up, I would have to repeat variable names over and over  for each elif line.

Comment: Check the second version of the code, it's better to work with than the first for larger arguments.

Comment: Are you you this is correct? The "modes" variable never gets used.

Comment: `check = mode.split()` it's used to check that the input is no more than 1 variable.

Comment: In that case, I think the following could be shorter isn't it?:
m = [creation_mode, existence_mode, integrity_mode];
if len([v for v in m if v is True]) is 1:

Comment: You still need to use the `split()` and you can use `if len([v for v in check if mode in m]) is 1:` Updated the answer as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you please give me an example in which mode.split() will be necessary? I am just not able to see that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81350/discussion-between-leb-and-chris-from-local-group).

Answer (score 2):

When we say that you don't want to do validation of input, the idea is that you can probably re-organize your code so that most of that validation is not necessary. For example, suppose you split it into 3 functions, such as below.

```
def create_mode():
    # Do X

def existence_mode():
    # Do Y

def integrity_mode():
    # Do Z
```

Because of the names of the function, and the fact that they have to explicitly call the function by name, it is pretty unlikely that they will pass the wrong arguments. Because of that, very little validation is needed. In fact, for this example it seems there are no arguments at all, so zero validation.

Comment: As stated by @BrenBarn, I think re-organization could be what I am looking for. Or maybe putting the 3 methods in a class?  I just don't know if using a class for small validations is Pythonic. I once heard that people "tend to over use classes" even when they are not needed (like in this case). I guess I have been learning Python under that philosophy and I don't even know if that is the right mindset, what do you think?

Comment: A good rule of thumb is "If you're not sure, then you don't need a class". Go with 3 functions. Once you have more experience, this decision will become a little easier (not a lot easier haha).

Answer (score 0):

Here are two other possible approaches you could take.

The first example ensures that only one mode can be actioned by passing the mode as a single parameter. This would make it easier to add further modes in the future.

```
creation_mode = 1
existence_mode = 2
integrity_mode = 3

def controls_validation_v2(mode):

    if mode == creation_mode:
        print("creation")
    elif mode == existence_mode:
        print("existence")
    elif mode == integrity_mode:
        print("integrity")
    else:
        raise ValueError("invalid mode")

controls_validation_v2(creation_mode)
```

The second approach is less obvious. Boolean variables do equate to 0 or 1, so this COULD be used to total their values to ensure that the total is exactly 1. The `raise` should never be reached unless the code is changed.

```
def controls_validation_v3(creation_mode=False, existence_mode=False, integrity_mode=False):

    if creation_mode + existence_mode + integrity_mode != 1:
        print("only one true argument is allowed")
    elif creation_mode:
        print("creation")
    elif existence_mode:
        print("existence")
    elif integrity_mode:
        print("integrity")
    else:
        raise ValueError("At least one arg required.")
```

Comment: Thanks, to me it seems kind of strange to set the global variables for this simple scenario. Your second option sounds much better to me. However as stated by @BrenBarn, I think re-organization could be what I am looking for. I am not a fan of having to re-write all arguments inside the function just for validation, because I have many validations and in most cases I have up to ten different modes, so having to list them again could become a lot work and difficult to maintain.

Comment: I agree, re-organization is probably the best, but it is always good to see a few alternatives. The emphasis on the first solution was on code clarity, making it as easy as possible to see the intent of the code. If this had been written in C/C++, then an enumerated type could have been used, or the variables would have been declared 'static const'.

Comment: Thanks I agree, the more options the better.